# Mysql sudden high disk usage when connections increased

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

recently we had an incident where because of a slowdown in an external service, the number of processes on the web server increased a lot. This caused mysql to reach max connections. However, the strange part was that after a while the mysql server disk I/O increased drastically and History list length started growing.

After analysis it looks like we hit the table_open_cache limit that led to a lot of fsyncs. I'm not completely able to understand if this is a possible explanation and why would opening tables require fsyncs?

We're using MySQL 5.6.40

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: looks like a hack where a connection was kept open( history length), and repeatedly did 'FLUSH TABLES'. Could be wrong, try looking in a binary logs and show global status for other changes. Or your active tables is so close to the table cache limit that they are closed so frequently.

Comment: or a mysqldump on a production server with some really bad combination of options like --single-transaction and --lock-tables at the same time.

Comment: If you could provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES;` and RAM size, I might find some other clues.  (More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the reason for this. It was because of the default values for **innodb_io_capacity** and **innodb_io_capacity_max** variables. The default value 200 is quite low for a high IOPS and CPU machine handline lots of writes.